# How to create a custom admin panel in WordPress for an existing non-WordPress application

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an existing PHP/MySQL application (non-WP). I'm showing bits and pieces of this application via iframes in a WP site. Right now the client has two admins; WP and my own custom admin and it's inconvenient for them.

What I want to achieve is to be able to show my custom admin inside WP. Every section of my admin is quite simple and with few controls so I don't mind doing a re-write to adapt this code to WP.

Having never really developed anything related to WordPress I need to know conceptually how to approach this. I don't need for code samples but rather the steps involved in all of this. Any gotchas from experienced WP developers are quite welcome too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can develop a WordPress plugin for your non-WP application.

Here's the approach I would try (you only say your app is quite simple, so I'm just assuming it's made of few pages/forms):

- [Create a plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) that leverage WP authentication
- Show your app inside iframes in the WP admin panel
- Change your app UI in order to match or use the WP admin panel one.

I did this in the past and having an iframe to be showed in the WP admin it's quite easy and users are happy to have just one authentication point.

Comment: Thanks, this looks easier than what I initially expected. I have a couple of questions though: 1) I'm Googling how to leverage the WP authentication on a plugin but keep coming up with frontend authentication plugins. By just writing -say- an empty plugin, wouldn't I be already leveraging WP's authentication? 2) If I show my admin page in an iframe, how can I protect it from being accessed directly (if prying eyes seem to find the iframe URL for example)?

Comment: 1. By writing an empty plugin you'll have the authentication for free.

Comment: 2. You can hide or encrypt your app and use readfile() or similar in the plugin to printout code coming from your phpapp without make it "easy" to be accessed.